# Why is an area of my animal crossing new horizon island lagging?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I am currently collecting every single fish and bug in the game 3 at a time to have Flick and CJ make commissions.

Here is part of my collection over 50 items which i managed to get a photo of:

[image: animal crossing new horizon fish bug collection at september 11 2020]

When the rain happened as seen in the image it started to lag in this area.  It has been lagging there ever so slightly

I have collections also inside my house mostly bugs because I had just finished Flick's Bug Off and made a room just for bugs which is already full of beetles.

I also made another one north of the town which has over 50 items also but it does not lag there.

Will this cause my game to crash?

I don't want to lose all this progress to a crash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't lose progress to a crash as far as I know. The game has an autosave feature so you can't lose anything.

The lag is likely caused by a large number of items along with the rain, which is slightly straining the GPU (nothing to worry about). As for why it's only happening in this particular location, it's possibly because of where you are; the bottom of the map means it's possible for a camera to need to render a lot of your island, so my guess is that the GPU is not culling things that are further back, leading the game to need to be rendering a lot of things at once